# Process Emulation

Tags: windows, fork, posix, simulation, createprocess

I want to simulate a video process, but I have no much clue about it as the code of process simulation is done by using fork() (POSIX), but now I am going to do it in Windows. Is it ok to use createProcess() ? I just needs some sort of **guidance/clues** only actually.

Video:
Video is simulated as a thread that tries to receive cpu 60 times per second
and uses 40% cpu. This would be quite a demanding video playback at 60fps. Like
the audio simulator it ignores caching, drivers and video cards. As per audio,
video is benchmarked with the real time option.

A little bit sample code in Posix:

```
/* We emulate video by using 40% cpu and waking for 60fps */
#define VIDEO_INTERVAL  (1000000 / 60)
#define VIDEO_RUN   (VIDEO_INTERVAL * 40 / 100)
void emulate_video(struct thread *th)
{
    unsigned long long deadline;
    sem_t *s = &th->sem.stop;
    struct timespec myts;

    th->decasecond_deadlines = 1000000 / VIDEO_INTERVAL * 10;
    deadline = get_usecs(&myts);

    while (1) {
        deadline = periodic_schedule(th, VIDEO_RUN, VIDEO_INTERVAL,
            deadline);
        if (!trywait_sem(s))
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you simulate `fork` with `CreateThread`, unless it's followed by `exec`, in which case you ues `CreateProcess`.

The `fork` system call creates a clone of your process. The `exec` system call loads a new program into your process, replacing the old program.

Comment: It's true that in many cases CreateThread() is the most appropriate replacement for fork(), but note that you can't just expect it to work without making other (usually substantial) changes to the code.  Threads share the same address space (global variables, etc.) whereas fork() creates a brand new address space that is a copy of the existing one.  The OPs existing code more likely than not expects a new address space, and will fail horribly if it doesn't get one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: In this case it looks like the OP just wants to run a busy loop in the other thread, so it should work fine. In most other cases you're right, though.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Yes, that might well be the case.